# Do you know how to ALWAYS show the keayboard on a ContentPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I got a small question for you. I am currently developing an application, based on Xamarin.Forms, and, on a ContentPage, i would like to always (yes i mean always always) show the keyboard. There is a textfield and some buttons or list, and when I click/tap on it, keayboard is hidden (and that is the standard behavior).

But here, I do not want if possible, to set the focus on the field for every action possible on the page. And even if I do that, we can see that the keyboard disappear and is shown back just after (trust me, me eyes are crying when it blink :)).

So, is it possible to set somewhere that we want to always show/display the keyboard ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Actually , it is not a good decision to keep the keyboard on the ContentPage , it will block other event like scroll and tap .

If you do want to implement it. You could define a default entry and set it onfocus when you finish editing other enrties .

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

   <Entry x:Name="defaultEntry" HeightRequest="0.1" WidthRequest="0.1" Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused" />

   <Entry HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="40" Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused" />

</StackLayout>
```

```
   bool IsNeedShowKeyBoard=true ;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Entry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsNeedShowKeyBoard)
        {
            defaultEntry.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Change the property **IsNeedShowKeyBoard** to false when start to scroll or you want to edit other entry .

Comment: Hello Lucas, thanks for your solution. But in fact, I tried it and keyboard blink when i do other actions, it is not really fancy. 'Cause I loose focus on the entry during the other action, and give it focus back then, so keyboard quickly hide and show.

Comment: But maybe it could be possible to add a keyboard as a control in the content page ?

Comment: You could create a custom "keyboard" with button on it and set the click event of each  character  button .

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am currently trying. It maybe the most appriopriate solution for my usage.
Thanks a lot anyway

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I will develop my own custom keyboard. With that solution, I will be able to let it be shown every time.