# Xamarin forms iOS CollectionView steals focus after ItemsSource property is changed

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uisearchbar

I have a page with a collection view and a search bar that filters its contents.

I want the filtering to happen as the user types in the search bar, so I bind the `TextChanged` event of the `SearchBar` to a command in the view model, like so

```
var eventToCommandBehavior = new EventToCommandBehavior()
{
     EventName = nameof(searchBar.TextChanged),
};
     eventToCommandBehavior.SetBinding(EventToCommandBehavior.CommandProperty, nameof(MyViewModel.StartOrResetSearchTimerCommand));
     searchBar.Behaviors.Add(eventToCommandBehavior);
```

In the view model:

```
public ICommand StartOrResetSearchTimerCommand => new Command(() =>
{
        StartOrResetSearchTimer();
});

private void StartOrResetSearchTimer()
{
     if (!timerStarted)
     {
          searchTimer = new Timer(_ => PerformSearch(), null, searchTimeout, searchTimeout);
          timerStarted = true;
     }
     else
          ResetTimer();
}

private void PerformSearch()
{
     //my code
     OnPropertyChanged(collectionViewItemsSourceBinding);
}
```

The `StartOrResetSearchTimerCommand` filters the `ItemsSource` binding, and calls `OnPropertyChanged(itemsSourceBinding)` to update the UI.

On Android and UWP everything works as expected. However on iOS, when `OnPropertyChanged` is called, the focus moves out of the search bar, resulting to the soft keyboard being closed after each keyboard input.

Has anyone else encountered this? Any suggestions?

I have already tried not using this approach, and only filter the `ItemsSource` when the search button is pressed, which works, when there is something to search for (ie, there is some input in the search bar)
When the search bar text is empty (ie after Backspace) then the search button is greyed out.

**Update**
For now, I am using this workaround:
Perfom the search only when the search button is pressed, and on `TextChanged`, check if the text is empty and reset the `ItemsSource`worka

Comment: After the OnPropertyChanged why not just call a method in your view that returns focus?

Comment: Yes, I will try that, it looks like the only way forward for now. I will update the post when I get to it

Answer (score 1):

TextChanged is called anytime the text in the query box is changed. You can use this event to update your ItemsSource when the Text of the searchbar changes. You can refer to [this part of the official example](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/UserInterface/SearchBarDemos/SearchBarDemos/SearchBarDemos/SearchBarRealtimeCodePage.cs#:%7E:text=%7D%3B-,searchBar.TextChanged%20%2B%3D%20OnTextChanged%3B,%7D,-%7D). First, given your ItemsSource, when you enter text in the searchbar, call the OnTextChanged event to update your ItemsSource, so that the real-time search keyboard will not lose focus.

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I am doing, no? I am binding the `TextChanged` event to a Command using `EventToCommandBehavior`. Regarding the official example, it does not use MVVM as the `searchResults` are in the same file. In my case, I need to call `OnPropertyChanged` to update the UI, and this is what removes the focus.

Comment: OnPropertyChanged is called every time the user types in the search bar to change the UI, so you can try to customize the keyboard to always show on the page, you can refer to the thread ["Do you know how to ALWAYS show the keayboard on a ContentPage"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60324267/do-you-know-how-to-always-show-the-keayboard-on-a-contentpage)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sorry that I am being late in my replies, I don't have much time to spend on this. I will try re-assigning focus back to the search bar after each key is pressed and I will update the post.

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Comment: Using `TextChanged` no. I have yet to try explicitly re-assigning the focus

Comment: You can try re-assigning the focus, waiting for your updates.